# Iterate over theme-variable files in SCSS

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

I want to create different css-themes for a WordPress theme by using theme setup files. The setup (simplified) would be as following:

```
/themes/_theme1.scss
/themes/_theme2.scss
/components/_file1.scss
/components/_file2.scss
/theme.scss
```

The idea is to enable easy theming by adding a class to the body of the document like `.theme-theme1` or `.theme-theme2`. In the files `_theme#.scss` I want to define variables like text colour, font sizes and so on. In `_file#.scss` the actual styles are defined.

My question now is, how to iterate over the theme setup files while filling up the files.scss.

Sample idea, Background colour:

```
body {

###foreach themefile###
&.theme# {
    background-color: $background-color;
}
###/foreach###

}
```

I know how to do this with only one theme available in the resulting CSS file, but I want to make ALL themes available in the resulting CSS. Feel free to ask more details as I am not sure if I explain me right.

Is there a way to create this stylesheet via some kind of foreach loops through variables in theme files or does it have to be done with extra scss-rules per theme file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *somewhat* possible using a combo of `@import` with a `@mixin` to generate the styles. This method should produce minimal repeated code.

Here's how we'll setup the files.

```
- scss
  - themes
    - _theme1.scss
    - _theme2.scss
  - _theme.scss
  - styles.scss
```

The `_` prefix on some of the files prevent them from being compiled into CSS to keep our build nice and clean. Now let's go through the contents of the files:

**_theme1.scss**

```
$theme-name: 'theme1';

$primary-color: red;
$primary-font-size: 24px;
```

**_theme2.scss**

```
$theme-name: 'theme2';

$primary-color: blue;
$primary-font-size: 12px;
```

This is an oversimplified example but should give the basic idea. Each theme file will contain only variables.

**_theme.scss**

```
@mixin themestyle() {
  body.#{$theme-name} {
    p {
      color: $primary-color;
      font-size: $primary-font-size;
    }

    .bordered {
      border: 3px solid $primary-color;
    }
  }
}
```

The `themestyle` mixin will contain all the styles for each theme, using the variables from the `/themes/_theme*.scss` files. The `body.#{$theme-name}` will create a selector like `body.theme1` or `body.theme2`, depending on the current value of the `$theme-name` variable.

In this demo I'm styling on a `p` tag but this could easily be extended to all elements/selectors for your site. The important thing to remember is all styles need to be inside the `body.#{$theme-name}` selector.

Now the final, and least [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) part. The `styles.scss` file will import each theme file then call the `themestyle` mixin to generate the styles for each theme.

**styles.scss**

```
@import 'themes/theme';

/* Theme 1 Styles */
@import 'themes/theme1';
@include themestyles();

/* Theme 2 Styles */
@import 'themes/theme2';
@include themestyles();
```

The repeated `@import/@include` is required because it's not possible to `@import` within a loop or mixin, or this could be optimized a bit more.

Once `styles.scss` is compiled the output will be:

```
/* Theme 1 Styles */
body.theme1 p {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px; }
body.theme1 .bordered {
  border: 3px solid red; }

/* Theme 2 Styles */
body.theme2 p {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 12px; }
body.theme2 .bordered {
  border: 3px solid blue; }
```

These themes can now be implemented by adding a class to the `body` tag, like `<body class="theme1">` or `<body class="theme1">`.

Here's a [Cloud9 project](https://ide.c9.io/brettdewoody/scss-theme-files) showing the setup.

Comment: HINT: In `styles.scss` the first import is wrong. Don't use `@import 'themes/theme';` use `@import 'theme';` So drop the folder name "themes/" because the _theme.scss in not inside that folder